# Подсказки для пермишенов

Tags: java, android

Как сделать подсказки для пермишенов как вот в ccleaner?
На скриншоте обращаю ваше внимание на то что пермишен отображение поверх окна отключено. Это как будто `BottomDialogFragment` изображается, а `Activity` настроек открыто в нашем приложении как родное. Так как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос кроется в этом коде

```
TaskStackBuilder.create( this )
        .addNextIntent( intentOnBottom )
        // use this method if you want "intentOnTop" to have it's parent chain of activities added to the stack. Otherwise, more "addNextIntent" calls will do.
        .addNextIntentWithParentStack( intentOnTop )
        .startActivities();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего внизу не `bottomNavigationView` находится а диалоговое окно которое можно закрыть. Закрытие делается либо через тулбар которые впилить в диалоговое окно либо проще будет вручную его все сделать. Теперь к тому как сделать такое окошко - все вероятнее всего придется сделать вручную или почти вручную так как это уж очень кастомное `view`. Вот например создание диалога и прикрепление его внизу:

```
val dialog = Dialog(Objects.requireNonNull(context))
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.log_out_dialogue)


val window = dialog.window
val wlp = window!!.attributes
wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
window.attributes = wlp



Objects.requireNonNull<Window>(dialog.window).setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
dialog.show()
```

Это один из вариантов реализации. Вариант номер два - сделать при помощи bottomSheetDialog или библиотеки для этого элемента. Вот есть [туториал_1](https://androidwave.com/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment-in-android/), [туториал_2](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295), [туториал_3](https://habr.com/ru/post/309200/) и [туториал_4](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/). Вот так же есть библиотеки для такого вида view: [1](https://github.com/prongbang/BottomSheetDialog), [2](https://github.com/javiersantos/BottomDialogs) и [3](https://github.com/marcoscgdev/DialogSheet). Но тут нужно понимать что при нажатии на кнопку крестика, как например у приведенное вам программы, вы должны будете его либо полностью либо частично скрывать следуя логике этой кнопки. Так же если соберетесь все-таки делать самостоятельно bottomSheetDialog то вот [guideline](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom/#bottom-sheets-modal-bottom-sheets) по material design. Ну а как все прилепить к приложению то тут все проще - делаете например фрагмент или dialogFragment с toggle button для переключения настройки приложения, внизу крепите ваш диалог и делаете переход на этот фрагмент.

### UPDATE

Более подробно о реализации:

1. Я бы не советовал использовать активность для решения такой простой задачи в виду ее (активности) громоздкости. Если попроще - вы на суперкомпьютере будете работать в ворде или рисовать в paint (это лично мое мнение которое может быть ошибочным). Поэтому я бы выбрал либо обычный фрагмент либо dialogFragment.
2. Дальше как это все связать с остальным приложением. Для перехода в dialogFragment я делаю так:

   ```
   val fullScreenDialog = FilterScreen()
   val ft = Objects.requireNonNull<FragmentManager>(fragmentManager).beginTransaction()
   fullScreenDialog.show(ft, fullScreenDialog.TAG)
   ```

и вот куда я перехожу:

```
class FilterScreen : DialogFragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    val TAG = FilterScreen::class.java.simpleName

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false)


        return view
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val dialog = dialog
        if (dialog != null) {
            val width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            Objects.requireNonNull<Window>(dialog.window).setLayout(width, height)
        }
    }

}
```

и уже тут вы можете обработку всех действий и логику добавить для работы с включением разрешения. Это пример как использовать dialogFragment.

Случай №2 - используем фрагмент (хотя по моему скромному мнению разницы большой нету):

1. Переходим в фрагмент из активности:

   ```
   val myFr= MyFr()

   supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentContainerT, myFr).addToBackStack(null).commit()
   ```
2. Вот например фрагмент:

   ```
   class JobsList : Fragment(){

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                             savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

   val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobs_list, container, false)
    }
   }
   ```

ну и дальше уже по аналогии.

P.S. Я бы вам еще советовал добавить отслеживание нужных вам разрешений приложения. Чтобы например если разрешение есть или оно получено, то перейти на этот экран настроек было нельзя.

Comment: Можете чуть подробнее рассказать пожалуйста как раз таки как мы запускаем эту активити с настройками + диалоговое окно снизу

Comment: @sakuraso13, обновил ответ :)

Comment: я правильно понял что в активити настроек мы переходим из `DialogFragment/Fragment`

Comment: если  я правильно понял то у вас приложение должно иметь такую настройку, для этого из активности нужно перейти в `DialogFragment/Fragment` а не наоборот

Comment: Нет нет, вот это активити с пермишеном это активити настроек системных, я туда перехожу вот так `startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName())), 787);`

Comment: а вы что хотите тогда сделать? Я так понял что вы хотите такое же сделать только для своего приложения и чтобы никуда за пределы приложения выходить не нужно было???

Comment: @Andrew, получить привелегии, не выходя за пределы, нельзя - можно только открыть окно системных настроек, либо запросить через (опять же системный) диалог, где юзер их выдаст. Вопрос ТС в том, чтобы добавить самописную подсказку ко всему этому, а не надеяться, что юзер там сам разберётся.

Comment: @woesss, я просто судорожно размышляю правильно ли я понял ТС и согласовывается ли ответ с его вопросом))) если суть только в инструкции то я думаю что диалог+фрагмент должны помочь))

Comment: @sakuraso13, а может это и есть их собственная активность - или после перемещения ползунка не выводится запрос в диалоге, а сразу привелегия активируется?

Comment: Я вот тоже над этим задумался потому что данное окно очень системное))) плюс для перехода на него используется интент

Comment: @Andrew суть вопроса заключается в том, как открывая левую активити, а в нашем случае это активити настроек с пермишеном, вывести такое же диалоговое окно. Одно я заметил, то что активити настроек как будто часть нашего приложения.